# REGEX matching with any character(s) between 2 strings

Tags: java, regex

[image]

I tried this with a regex tester and it works. But why can't i get it work for JAVA.
I am hoping to search for `neither..........nor`

I want to count how many `neither` something`nor` are in a string : `"Neither u or me are human"`.

I have tried :

```
occurrence += sentence.split( "(?i)\\Wneither.+nor\\W" ).length - 1;
```

but it is not working because the output `System.out.print(occurrence)` result is `0`.

I thought `\\W` stands for non-word character while `.+` means any character(s).

How can I get a `occurrence` result of `1`?

Comment: *this is not working* is not a problem description, and *any solution* to a problem you've not explained is not a question. What **specific problem** are you having with that regex, and what **specific question** would you like us to answer for you?

Comment: There are zero occurrences of "neither.+nor" in "Neither u or me are human". Also at least 1 occurrence of grammar errors :-)

Comment: If you're looking for `neither ABC nor` (where _ABC_ is any word) then it's correct that your `"Neither u or me are human"` gives result of zero. If the string was `"Neither u nor me are human"` then you could expect result of 1, isn't it? Is your question really just _"How to count how many `neither` and how many `nor` are used in sentence"_?

Answer (score 1):

You can count occurrences with this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(neither|nor)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Neither u or me are human");

int count = 0;
while (matcher.find())
    count++;

System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Asker has updated (changed the rules) of expected result. They want specifically (`neither` + `*` + `nor`) where `*` is anything between the two words _neither_ and _nor_ or at least to my understanding